# Is there archive mechanizem for ElasticSearch docs?

Tags: elasticsearch, archive

I have elastic search container which holds 12 indexes (index per month) when must of the data is history data. 
I looking for mechanizem which save only the information about the current day and when the day passed It will pass the data to the index of the current month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [index lifecycle management(ILM)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) where you can define various policies on the management of your indices, like moving the indices, deleting the indices etc.

More specifically you can look for a [automate rollover of ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management) which seems to be the use-case of yours.